# Three level iteration using v-for in v-tabs

Tags: for-loop, vue.js, tree, vuejs2

I choose a [Model Tree Structures with Child References](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-child-references/) for my three level dependency tree: firstLevel, secondLevel and Items

I have issue displaying each Items in their secondLevels parents, themself in their firstLevels parents.

You'll find my code right after but just a few words to explain the philosophy of it.
First, I use the v-tabs to display the firstLevels. 
Then, in each firstLevel tabs, I display the list of corresponding secondLevels in v-toolbars by getting their id from an array (subLevels) contained in the current parent firstLevel object.

Until there, it's working.

But since I try to add a depth with the items - childs of secondLevels - it's not working anymore and I have a Vue Warning :

> [Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.

```
<template>
     <div>
      <v-layout id="admin-layout" justify-space-around column>
       <v-tabs
         v-model="activeFL"
         centered
         slider-color="blue"
         grow
       >
         <v-tab
           v-for="(firstLevel, index) in firstLevels"
           :key="index"
           ripple
         >
           Niveau {{ index + 1 }}
           </br>
           {{firstLevel.name}}
         </v-tab>
       </v-tabs>

       <v-tabs-items v-model="activeFL">
        <v-tab-item
          v-for="(firstLevel, index) in firstLevels"
          :key="index"
        >
        <v-toolbar
          color="pink"
          dark
          v-for="(secondLevelId, index) in firstLevel.subLevels"
          :key="secondLevelId"
        >
          <v-toolbar-title>{{getSLById(secondLevelId).name}}</v-toolbar-title>
          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
        </v-toolbar>

        <v-card>
          <v-container
            fluid
            grid-list-lg
          >
            <v-layout row wrap>
              <v-flex xs12
                v-for="(itemId, index) in currentSL.items"
                :key="itemId"
              >
                <v-card color="blue-grey darken-2" class="white--text">
                  <v-card-title primary-title>
                    <div>
                      <div class="headline">{{getItemById(itemId)}}</div>
                    </div>
                  </v-card-title>
                </v-card>
              </v-flex>

            </v-layout>
          </v-container>
        </v-card>
            </v-tab-item>
          </v-tabs-items>
        </v-layout>
     </div>
    </template>
    <script>
    export default {
      data () {
        return {
          name: this.$store.state.user.name,
          dialog: false,
          error: '',
          dialogError: '',
          deleteFL: false,
          deleteSL: false,
          deletinglevel: {},
          firstLevels: [],
          secondLevels: [],
          items: [],
          activeFL: 0,
          currentSL: {},
          currentItem: {}
        }
      },
      created () {
        this.getFirstLevels()
        this.getSecondLevels()
        this.getItems()
      },
      methods: {
        getSLById (id) {
          return this.currentSL = this.secondLevels.find(x => x._id === id)
        },
        getItemById (id) {
          return this.currentItem = this.items.find(x => x._id === id)
        },
        async getFirstLevels () {
          try {
            const firstLevels = await LevelService.getFirstLevels()
            this.firstLevels = Object.keys(firstLevels.data).map((key) => {
              return firstLevels.data[key]
            })
          } catch (e) {
            this.error = e.response.data.error
          }
        },
        async getSecondLevels () {
          try {
            const secondLevels = await LevelService.getSecondLevels()
            this.secondLevels = Object.keys(secondLevels.data).map((key) => {
              return secondLevels.data[key]
            })
          } catch (e) {
            this.error = e.response.data.error
          }
        },
        async getItems () {
          try {
            const items = await ItemService.getItems()
            this.items = Object.keys(items.data).map((key) => {
              return items.data[key]
            })
          } catch (e) {
            this.error = e.response.data.error
          }
        }
      }
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: I actually think that your issue is you're not structuring your mongo relationships correctly. You should really look into [one-to-one relationships](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-embedded-one-to-one-relationships-between-documents/). This way you can just fetch the first levels and loop over the children without needing to juggle ID's on the client side or make so many ajax calls.

Comment: Thx @Ohgodwhy, I've thought about this model but as I have three levels, may I embed the items in the embedded secondLevels ? Is it a correct way to do so ?

Comment: You shouldn't worry about juggling tiers of levels this way. All levels should have a parent ID which can be nullable. If the parent ID exists, it is included in the mongo query. This way you're just looping through the children client side and not worrying about specifically determining at which level they appear in mongo.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but my data should be stored this way : 
`{
   _id: "someObjectId",
   name: "A firstLevel",
   secondLevels: 
    [
      {
        name: "A secondLevel",
        items: [
          {
            name: "An item"
          },
          {
            name: "A second item"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        name: "An other secondLevel",
        items: []
      }
    ]
}`